# Некоректная отписка от событий через Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, события

Возможно я что-то не понимаю, но...

Имеется некий класс (например `MyClass`), генерирующий событие. Например оно называется `EndedEvent`.
Так же имеется `UserControl`, в котором инициализируется экземпляр класса `Myclass`. `UserControl` при нажатии на кнопку подписывается на событие `EndedEvent`. Ниже попытаюсь примести использумые куски кода и описать взаимодействие.
Обертка для Диспетчера:

```
public static class FastDispatcher
{
    static public void CodeBlock<T>(T Target, Action _codeBlock) where T : System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    {
       Target.Dispatcher.Invoke(_codeBlock);
    }
}
```

Контрол:

```
public partial class MyConrol : UserControl
{
    MyClass myClass;
    public SocialGetter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClass= new MyClass(); ;
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myClass.EndedEvent+= myClass_EndedEvent;
        myClass.Start("строка");      
    }

    private void myClass_EndedEvent()
    {
        FastDispatcher.CodeBlock(this, () =>
        {
            textBox1.Text = "OK";
            myClass.EndedEvent -= myClass_EndedEvent;
        });
    }
}
```

Класс:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public delegate EndedEventDel();
    public EndedEventDel EndedEvent;
    void Start(string str)
    {
        ActionDF.EndedEvent += ADF_EndedEvent;
        ActionDF.Add(str);      
    }
    private void ADF_EndedEvent()
    {
       if (EndedEvent!= null) EndedEvent(this);
       ActionDF.EndedEvent -= ADF_EndedEvent;
    }
}
```

Dataflow-очередь:

```
public static class ActionDF
{
    public delegate EndedEventDel();
    public EndedEventDel EndedEvent;
    public TransformBlock<string,string> actionblock //допустим
    void Start(string str)
    {
        actionblock = new TransfonmBlock<string,string>(n => {
            Threed.Sleep(2000);
            if(EndedEvent!=null) EndedEvent();
            return "";
        });     
    }

    public void Add(string str)
    {
        actionblock.Post(str);
    }
}
```

Дальше я выношу на форму 2 своих `MyControl` и нажимаю на каждом кнопку. В итоге сообщение ОK выводится только на тот `MyControl`, в котором я нажал кнопку первой.
Если вынести отписку от события в контроле и поставить её в событие кнопки перед подпиской, то всё работает корректно.

Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: А зачем вам `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate (){ _codeBlock();})).Wait();`, если можно просто `Dispatcher.Invoke(_codeBlock)`?

Comment: @VladD, незнаю, возможно я был упорот, либо писал это в 5 утра, но проблемы этого не исправило.

Comment: Не, это не должно исправить проблему, просто выглядит существенно проще, а делает в точности то же самое.

Comment: @VladD, ну, с этим сложно поспорить:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположу, что проблема вот в чём: ваше событие `ActionDF.EndedEvent` не сообщает, что именно завершилось.

Результат:

1. `MyClass` №1 подписывается на `ActionDF.EndedEvent` и запускает первое задание через `ActionDF.Add`.
2. `MyClass` №2 тоже подписывается на `ActionDF.EndedEvent` и запускает второе задание.
3. Первое задание заканчивается, срабатывает `ActionDF.EndedEvent`.
4. *Оба* экземпляра `MyClass` получают его одновременно. Оба отписываются от `ActionDF.EndedEvent`

В этой ситуации выполнение должно идти неправильно, но с кодом, который вы привели, вывод должен быть одновременно у обеих контролов. Перепроверьте, что происходит у вас в реальности.

Comment: То, что доктор прописал! Благодарю!

Comment: @BwehaaFox: Вот и отлично! Одной загадкой меньше.

Comment: @VladD а как сделать так, чтобы такой ситуации не было? Просто интересная задачка

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov: Например, передавать в аргументах события ссылку на завершённое задание каким-нибудь образом. Или вовсе не использовать события, а при отправлении задания на выполнение получать назад `Task<ResultT>`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо.

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov: Пожалуйста!